# How to avoid GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor problems?

Tags: java, serialization, constructor, garbage-collection, accessor

We have a Java App that receives SOAP requests, and after a lot of requests we notice that the GC stops the world to unload a lot of GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor classes. This is a big performance impact.

Does anyone know how to avoid this or at least significantly reduce the count of GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor classes created?

Comment: Why is this tagged gcc (Gnu Compiler Collection)? Did you mean to tag it gc (garbage collector)? Are you using gcj (Gnu Compiler for Java)?

Comment: I think it was a typo, I change it to `gc`

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the options:

```
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=30
```

Increases the number of calls through a Constructor/Method/Field before a native accessor will be "inflated" to a generated accessor.  The default is 15.

```
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=0
```

Disables inflation altogether.  Interestingly, this option does not seem to affect constructors, but it does work for methods.

You can test the options with a simple test app:

```
public class a {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      a.class.getDeclaredConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
    }
  }

  private static int x;
  public a() {
    new Throwable("" + x++).printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Edit (29-Dec-2013):** The `-Dsun.reflect.noInflation=true` option disables the inflation mechanism and instead immediately uses generated accessors, so you don't want that option.

Comment: As a matter of fact, setting noInflation to true will cause all access to be done by byte code generation. You want to set the threshold to zero or less.

Comment: @raphw You're right, thanks for correcting my misinformation! I've edited the post with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] we notice that the GC stops the world to unload a lot of 
>   GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor classes. This is a big performance 
>   impact.

As it is impossible to avoid if your application is using reflection, you may try using [CMS garbage collector](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/cms-6.html) to minimize the impact of the stop-the-world GC.

Answer (score 0):

From http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.programmer/2006-11/msg00122.html

> These classes are part of the
>   reflection mechanism. Since around
>   Java 1.3 reflection has been
>   implemented by generating classes to
>   perform the access. It's much faster
>   use, but takes longer to create and
>   upsets the permanent generation.
>
> Serialisation uses them to read/write
>   fields, execute methods (readObject,
>   writeObject, readObjectNoData,
>   readResolve) and call the
>   non-serialisable base class
>   constructor (this last code is not
>   verifiable).

It appears they're only used transiently to serialize/deserialize a given class of object. As the article points out, these are probably held using SoftReferences, so ensure that your app has plenty of memory, and these will be reclaimed less often.

Surprisingly, there doesn't appear to be any other solution.